# VBA to compare two columns and copy row

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel I am trying to make a macro that checks for two criteria in a row and copy it to another page. This is what I have so far. If I take out all of the AK references it does work on the first variable but the second one is causing me grief. Any thoughts? thank you for your time in advance.

```
Sub GenMonthWeekend()
Dim aj As Range
Dim ak As Range
Dim abc As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Month Raw Data")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Month Volume - Weekend")

abc = 2     ' Start copying to row 2 in target sheet
For Each aj In Source.Range("aj1:ak10000")   ' Do 10000 rows
    If aj = "1" And ak = "False" Then ' If colum aj is 1 and ak false copy
       Source.Rows(aj.Row).Copy Target.Rows(abc)
       abc = abc + 1
ElseIf aj = "7" And ak = "False" Then ' If colum aj is 7 and ak false copy
       Source.Rows(aj.Row).Copy Target.Rows(abc)
       abc = abc + 1
    End If
Next aj
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not setting a range to `ak`  Just because it is named the column reference does not make vba automatically assign the range to it.

Comment: Is `False` typed in or is it `FALSE` as in the acutual Boolean?

Comment: False is typed in the box

Answer (score 2):

Your range variable `ak` is not working the way you think it is.

Just loop through your column `AJ` and check the value in `AK` by using `Offset(,1)` which will look one column over to the right.

```
abc = 2
For Each aj In Source.Range("AJ1000")
    If aj = "1" And aj.offset(,1) = "False" Then
       Source.Rows(aj.Row).Copy Target.Rows(abc)
       abc = abc + 1
ElseIf aj = "7" And aj.offset(,1) = "False" Then
       Source.Rows(aj.Row).Copy Target.Rows(abc)
       abc = abc + 1
    End If
Next aj
```

---

You can clean this up by combining your criteria and using a `For i` loop.

```
Sub GenMonthWeekend()
Dim i As Range

Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Month Raw Data")
Dim Target As Worksheet: Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Month Volume - Weekend")

For i = 2 To 1000
    If (Source.Range("AJ" & i) = 1 Or Source.Range("AJ" & i) = 7) And Source.Range("AJ" & i).Offset(, 1) = "False" Then
        Source.Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(Target.Range("A" & Target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Since the output is the same on the if and Elseif you can combine them: `If (aj = "1" Or aj = "7") And aj.Offset(, 1) = "False" Then`

Comment: I was working on that right now and swapping this for an `For i = 1 to 1000` loop. Just addressing the main issue before editing

Comment: @RobbyStolle updated. May be worth while to check out a slightly cleaner approach. Easier to follow